# How do I disable headless mode in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, headless

Is it possible to disable headless mode in Firefox (so that nobody can use it)?

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1338004

Comment: What's your actual goal? Seems like this is just a mode for some internal testing, and needs to be specifically enabled with a command line flag. Why do you want to disable it?

Comment: Security. Don't enable things you don't use. Or others will use it. https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/security/chrome-and-firefox-headless-modes-may-spur-new-adware-and-clickfraud-tactics/

Answer (score 0):

In short, not without forking and rewriting parts of Firefox, or reverting to an older version. Judging by that Bugzilla tracker, it's a core component. You might also want to know that [Chrome has a headless feature too](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44398014/534406).

I don't think security is a big issue here - at least, no bigger than other security issues inherent in running software on a PC these days. In order to activate headless mode, the attacker would probably already need the ability to run arbitrary programs at the user level. That's my two cents.

Comment: Browsers are used to exfiltrate data because they are usually whitelisted and have to be executable for user internet access. All you need to hijack this is some one-liner, and it will be hard to discern legitimate browser actions from questionable ones and prevent those, unless you specifically detect headless mode. The user won't see anything suspicious. Standalone malware is more easily blockable.

Comment: I'm not sure what else to suggest! Browsing the internet is fraught with risks in so many different forms. If you're that concerned, you'd probably want your own custom browser build, or an OS environment specifically designed to be hardened against attack.